# Accessing https pages with python3

Tags: python-3.x, urllib3

I do not understand how to use `urllib3` or `requests` to connect to an https web site.  This is driving me nuts.  I have installed `certifi` and I see the default `.pem` file it provides.  I have tried to set the `requests.verify` option to `requests` to every `.pem` and `.crt` file on the machine my script runs on [I am not an admin on this device].  I get nothing but errors.

I switched to using `urllib3` and am now getting:

```
H:\Projects\MyScraper\venv\Scripts\python.exe H:/Projects/MyScraper/MyScraper.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\Projects\MyScraper\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "H:\Projects\MyScraper\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 343, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "H:\Projects\MyScraper\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 839, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "H:\Projects\MyScraper\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 344, in connect
    ssl_context=context)
  File "H:\Projects\MyScraper\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 342, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\ssl.py", line 407, in wrap_socket
    _context=self, _session=session)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\ssl.py", line 814, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\ssl.py", line 1068, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\ssl.py", line 689, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:777)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:/Projects/MyScraper/MyScraper.py", line 15, in <module>
    raw_html = HTTP.request('GET', 'https://portal.xsede.org/course-calendar/')
  File "H:\Projects\MyScraper\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\request.py", line 68, in request
    **urlopen_kw)
  File "H:\Projects\MyScraper\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\request.py", line 89, in request_encode_url
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
  File "H:\Projects\MyScraper\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 323, in urlopen
    response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
  File "H:\Projects\MyScraper\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 667, in urlopen
    **response_kw)
  File "H:\Projects\MyScraper\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 667, in urlopen
    **response_kw)
  File "H:\Projects\MyScraper\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 667, in urlopen
    **response_kw)
  [Previous line repeated 6 more times]
  File "H:\Projects\MyScraper\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "H:\Projects\MyScraper\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 398, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='portal.xsede.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /course-calendar/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:777)'),))

Process finished with exit code 1
```

My code looks like:

```
    #!/home/me/virtualenv/python3.6/3.6/bin/python

    import certifi
    import urllib3
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    HTTP = urllib3.PoolManager(
        cert_reqs='CERT_REQUIRED',
        ca_certs=certifi.where(),
        retries=10
    )

    raw_html = HTTP.request('GET', 'https://portal.xsede.org/course-calendar/')

    html = BeautifulSoup(raw_html, 'html.parser')
```

It blows up on the `raw_html = HTTP.request(...` line.  Ideas?

**Edit**

Huh, this has something to do with my target host.  If I go to `google.com` then several of my pem/crt files work.

Comment: It's certificate verify failed. Nothing much people here can help you with, you need the right content in .pem file.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, you are using wrong certificate to make request.

you can run this command to verify which certificate is used when any request is made, and then use that certificate in your request,

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect google.com:443
```

Please also make sure that you are passing `verify` the path to `CA_BUNDLE` file or directory with certificates of trusted CAs.

This list of trusted CAs can also be specified through the `REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE` environment variable.

If this doesn't work out for you can explicitly merge the [environment settings into your session](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/),

> When you are using the prepared request flow, keep in mind that it
>   does not take into account the environment. This can cause problems if
>   you are using environment variables to change the behaviour of
>   requests. For example: Self-signed SSL certificates specified in
>   REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE will not be taken into account. As a result an `SSL:
>   CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED` is thrown. You can get around this behaviour
>   by explicity merging the environment settings into your session:

from requests import Request, Session

```
s = Session()
req = Request('GET', url)

prepped = s.prepare_request(req)

# Merge environment settings into session
settings = s.merge_environment_settings(prepped.url, None, None, None, None)
resp = s.send(prepped, **settings)

print(resp.status_code)
```